# jQuery mobile youtube video black

Tags: jquery, ipad, jquery-mobile

I embedded a youtube video into a tabview and it works fine. The fact is that if I changed a tab I stopped the video via javascipt, but if I came back to the youtube video tab, the video frame is all in black. It is not possible to press start or anything.

I use this code to stop the video because I have a lot of pages with tab videos:

```
$('.byngitek').click(function () {
       var i = 0;
       $(".youtubeplayer").each(function () {
           $(this).attr("id", "youtubeplayer" + i);
           callPlayer("youtubeplayer" + i, "stopVideo");
           i++;
       });
   });
```

I grab some code for example here: http://jsfiddle.net/iruindegi/t3suE/

1-. Play de video

2-. Click on "Materiales" tab (it will stop the video and change tab)

3-. If you click again in the first tab (sorry I know that the code is not complete, but I´m in a rush)

4-. In Chrome, Firefox... works, I can see the video controllers and everything, but on the iPad is not working. Look screen captures.

before: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/856/img0034v.png/

after: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/46/img0035k.png/

any help?

thanks in advance

Comment: I hope the below worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pauseVideo` instead of `stopVideo`

> **player.pauseVideo():Void**
>
> Pauses the currently playing video. The final player state after this
>   function executes will be paused (2) unless the player is in the ended
>   (0) state when the function is called, in which case the player state
>   will not change.
>
> **player.stopVideo():Void**
>
> Stops and cancels loading of the current video. This function should
>   be reserved for rare situations when you know that the user will not
>   be watching additional video in the player. If your intent is to pause
>   the video, you should just call the pauseVideo function. If you want
>   to change the video that the player is playing, you can call one of
>   the queueing functions without calling stopVideo first.

Source: [Playback controls guide.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Playback_controls)

[Click me!](http://jsfiddle.net/t3suE/1/)

Comment: it seems to, it works ok on desktop browser and also on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.2 but no for iphone/ipad